# Can questions about CMS frameworks be posted on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions

Am I able to post a question on Stack Overflow if the context is specifically about a Wordpress framework?

If no, is there anywhere on the Stack Exchange I can ask this, about web development?

Comment: Eh, how about [wordpress.se]?

Comment: It is specifically about a framework though. I think that is not allowed on the Wordpress SE (like any theme/plugin questions)?

Comment: Dear VtC reviewers, CMS means: "content management system", like Joomla, Wordpress, Liferay and so on. I can only hope that the down & close votes were cast by users knowing well this abbreviation, although it is hard for me to really believe it.

Comment: @peterh There are lots of potential questions about CMS I can envisage. Some would be on-topic, some wouldn't. Without more details this question can't be answered.

Comment: @RobertLongson don't look now but two people answered it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker one of them pointed to the help centre which you could pretty much do with half the questions here. Not sure that's addressing the specifics of things. Your answer is much better and might be what the OP is looking for or it might not. Perhaps your mind reading equipment is simply better than mine.

Comment: @RobertLongson The question could be correctly answered by saying that they are ok, but they should be about their programming (and not, for example, about their usage).

Comment: We'd be able to be much more helpful if we had a sample question or two wouldn't we though? At least I'd like to hope so.

Answer (score 6):

We accept developer questions related to all CMSes (that are open source, or provide programmatic access to their innards).  It's important to note the questions must be developer focused; a general question like "How do I change the theme?" would not be on-topic.  You can also get support from [WordPress Stack Echange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com), whose [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com) says:

> WordPress Development is a question and answer site for WordPress developers and administrators. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites.
>
> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about theme and plugin development, development and management best practices and server configuration for WordPress. See what is on topic and what not on our help page. Please ask how to solve specific problems, not where to find existing plugins or themes.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, questions about Wordpress **development** can be on-topic on Stack Overflow.

The usual rules about topicality apply:

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic